# ActiveMQ - CreateSession failover timeout after a connection is resumed

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.6.0 and ActiveMQ NMS client.

I connect to the broker using the follow code:

```cs
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(
    "failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?transport.timeout=5000"
    );

connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();    
connection.Start();

connection.ConnectionResumedListener += OnConnectionResumed;
```

Then I stop the broker and start it again. After that in the method OnConnectionResumed

```cs
private void OnConnectionResumed()
{
    var session = connection.CreateSession();

    ...
}
```

I always get the failover timeout exception when try to create a session.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appeared because I had created a session in the thread where the
resumed call is made in.

The correct code is:

```cs
private void OnConnectionResumed()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var session = connection.CreateSession();

            ...
        });
}
```